# How can I modify edmx and reflect changes in the domainservice automatically?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, domainservices

I have a silverlight business application created with vs2010 and it is RIA service enabled, I added new table in the database and updated the edmx using (update model from database option), but I want to update the domain service class as well to include the new tables, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this automatically, but [this blog](http://www.riaservicesblog.net/Blog/post/How-to-setup-your-DomainService-using-partial-classes-for-easy-maintenance.aspx) seems helpful.
EDIT: If you use partial classes as suggested, then you can delete the DomainService1.cs class and use add new item to add the class again. Then using the built in wizard, re-check the entities you want to expose. The partial classes will hold your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have not found nothing better than:

- Add new DomainService that will work with new table;
- Copy generated code into existing(main) service (**Get***, Insert, Update, Delete etc.);
- Copy metadata;
- Delete "new" DomainService and "new" metadata files;

After these steps you'll get access to your table.

*NOTE:*

*-without Get- method client will not recognize any changes;